# Exception on System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Vector3d serialisation on wcf call

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization

I'm trying to send a class on wcf, I am having problems to serialize this class System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Vector3d. I get this exception

There was an error while trying to serialize parameter WEntityService:iState. 
The InnerException message was 'Type 'System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Vector3D' with data contract name 
'Vector3D:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Windows.Media.Media3D' is not expected. Consider 
using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, 
by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.'.
Please see InnerException for more details.

```
  [DataContract]
  public ref class WData
  {
  public:
    WData();

    [DataMember]
    Vector3D^ mLinearVelocity;

    [DataMember]
    System::String^ mName;
  };

 WData::WData()
    : mLinearVelocity(gcnew Vector3D(0.0, 0.0, 0.0))        
    , mName(gcnew System::String(' ', 1))
  {

  }
```

On the msdn web site http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms606682.aspx, you can see that Vector3D has Serializable attiribute. For the wcf serialisable type if I refer to this  web page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731923.aspx
Vector3D should be serializable for the wcf. Can someone explain me why It's not serialized. Thks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just add Vector3D to the list of known types? See example below at the data contract level. I think that should fix your problem.

```
[DataContract]
public class Book { }

[DataContract]
public class Magazine { }

[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(Book))]
[KnownType(typeof(Magazine))]
public class LibraryCatalog
{
    [DataMember]
    System.Collections.Hashtable theCatalog;
}
```

If you can't add a known type at the data contract level and have to add it at only the service contract level, you can do something like below -- add a [ServiceKnownTypeAttribute]!

```
// Apply the ServiceKnownTypeAttribute to the 
// interface specifying the type to include. Apply 
// the attribute more than once if needed.
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Widget))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Machine))]
[ServiceContract()]
public interface ICatalog2
{
    // Any object type can be inserted into a Hashtable. The 
    // ServiceKnownTypeAttribute allows you to include those types
    // with the client code.
    [OperationContract]
    Hashtable GetItems();
}
```